# The Bevel is not normally applied to a specific edge of the connected edge with Subdivision surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror, subdivision-surface, bevel

Some problems arise with the application of the `Subdivision Surface` modifier when trying to create the following model:

[image]

If you look closely at the picture, the `bevel` did not apply properly on only one edge.

[image]

I also put a set value in the `Crease` for the edge. However, the edge is described as strange as follows.

[image]
[image]

Q.Is there a way to make the edge look like any other beveled edge?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because there are two large n-gons, and the *Subdivision Modifier* doesn't like it.
Just cut them into quads, and everything will be fine.

Connect vertices to make quads.
*Vertex > Connect Vertex Path*
Shortcut: <kbd>J</kbd>

[image]

Compared results:

[image]

Comment: But why not connect all vertices of n-gons?

Comment: @bakuiseok Look carefully at the gif. I connected vertices so they form *quads*. There's no need to connect more of them, it would just form *triangles* :).